# JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD - API Level 21 - Application crashes

Tags: android

I'm using JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD. My application is running in the emulator. But when I test my tablet and phone, my application crashes.
This is because the JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD property works on API level 26.
But I want it to work in android 4.4.2.
Is this possible ?
Does the JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD feature work in android 4.4.2?
Any suggestions?

i tried this method but i couldn't

https://github.com/mathew-kurian/TextJustify-Android

Run Error

```
 `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.medicalsix.doctorsix, PID: 11989
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setJustificationMode(I)V in class Landroid/widget/TextView; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.widget.TextView' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
    at com.medicalsix.doctorsix.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11989 SIG: 9
Application terminated.`

Main Avtivity

```
package com.medicalsix.doctorsix;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    TextView textview,text;
    ImageView imageview;
    WebView webview;
    Button buttson;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = findViewById(R.id.text);

       text.setJustificationMode(Layout.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);





        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);







        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);



        hideItem();
        TwoFalse();
        ThreeFalse();
        FourFalse();







    }

    private void hideItem()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemone).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemtwo).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemthree).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemfour).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemfive).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemsix).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemclose).setVisible(false);



    }
    private void hideItemvisible()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemone).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemtwo).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemthree).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemfour).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemfive).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemsix).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemclose).setVisible(true);


    }
   /* private void hidecloseitem()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemclose).setVisible(true);

    }
    private void hidecloseitemfalse()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.itemclose).setVisible(false);


    }


    private void twocloseTrue()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoclose).setVisible(true);

    }
    private void twocloseFalse()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoclose).setVisible(false);


    }*/

    private void TwoFalse()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoclose).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwo).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twothree).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twofour).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twofive).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twosix).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoseven).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoeight).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twonine).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoteen).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoeleven).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotvelve).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twothirteen).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twofourteen).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twosixteen).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoseventeen).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoeigteen).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twonineteen).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwenty).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyone).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentytwo).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentythree).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyfour).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyfive).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentysix).setVisible(false);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyseven).setVisible(false);








    }
    private void TwoTrue()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoclose).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoone).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwo).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twothree).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twofour).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twofive).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twosix).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoseven).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoeight).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twonine).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoteen).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoeleven).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotvelve).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twothirteen).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twofourteen).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twosixteen).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoseventeen).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twoeigteen).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twonineteen).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwenty).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyone).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentytwo).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentythree).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyfour).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyfive).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentysix).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.twotwentyseven).setVisible(true);




    }
    private void ThreeFalse()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.threeclose).setVisible(false);








    }
    private void ThreeTrue()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.threeclose).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.threeone).setVisible(true);





    }

    private void FourFalse()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.fourclose).setVisible(false);








    }
    private void FourTrue()
    {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.fourclose).setVisible(true);
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.fourone).setVisible(true);





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);




        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

                hideItemvisible();
            //hidecloseitem();
            /*setTitle("First Fragment");
            First first = new First();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,first).commit();
            */
        }else if (id == R.id.itemclose) {
            hideItem();
           // hidecloseitemfalse();
        }else if (id == R.id.itemone) {
            setTitle("One Fragment deneme ");
            One one = new One();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,one).commit();

        }else if (id == R.id.itemtwo) {
            setTitle("Two Fragment");
            Two two = new Two();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,two).commit();

        }else if (id == R.id.itemthree) {
            setTitle("Three Fragment");
            Three three = new Three();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,three).commit();

        }else if (id == R.id.itemfour) {
            setTitle("Four Fragment");
            Four four = new Four();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,four).commit();

        }else if (id == R.id.itemfive) {
            setTitle("Five Fragment");
            Five five = new Five();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,five).commit();

        }else if (id == R.id.itemsix) {
            setTitle("Six Fragment");
            Six six = new Six();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,six).commit();

        }else if (id == R.id.twoclose) {
            TwoFalse();
        }else if (id == R.id.twoone) {

            TwoTrue();

        }
        else if (id == R.id.threeclose) {

            ThreeFalse();

        }else if (id == R.id.threeone) {

           ThreeTrue();

        }
        else if (id == R.id.fourclose) {

            FourFalse();

        }else if (id == R.id.fourone) {

            FourTrue();

        }else if (id == R.id.twotwo) {

            setTitle("İzofluran");
            Seven seven = new Seven();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,seven).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twothree) {

            setTitle("Porfiria");
            Eight eight = new Eight();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,eight).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twofour) {

            setTitle("Amanita Phalloides");
            Nine nine = new Nine();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,nine).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twofive) {

            setTitle("Civa Zehirlenmesi");
            Teen teen = new Teen();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,teen).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twosix) {

            setTitle("Aldrete Skorlaması");
            Eleven eleven = new Eleven();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,eleven).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twoseven) {

            setTitle("Baker Simionescu");
            Twelve twelve = new Twelve();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twelve).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twoeight) {

            setTitle("TLR4-Sıcak Çarpması");
            Thirteen thirteen = new Thirteen();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,thirteen).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twonine) {

            setTitle("Süksinilkolin");
            Fourteen fourteen = new Fourteen();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,fourteen).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twoteen) {

            setTitle("Tubokürarin");
                Sixteen sixteen = new Sixteen();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,sixteen).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twoeleven) {

            setTitle("Remifentanil");
            Seventeen seventeen = new Seventeen();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,seventeen).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotvelve) {

            setTitle("Santral Sinir");
            Eigteen eigteen = new Eigteen();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,eigteen).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twothirteen) {

            setTitle("Nondepolarizan Bloğu");
            Nineteen nineteen = new Nineteen();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,nineteen).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twofourteen) {

            setTitle("Depolarizan Bloğu");
            Twenty twenty = new Twenty();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twenty).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twosixteen) {

            setTitle("Etomidat");
            Twentyone twentyone = new Twentyone();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentyone).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twoseventeen) {

            setTitle("Halotan Hepatotoksisitesi");
            Twentytwo twentytwo = new Twentytwo();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentytwo).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twoeigteen) {

            setTitle("Bupivakain Kondroliz");
            Twentythree twentythree = new Twentythree();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentythree).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twonineteen) {

            setTitle("Yağ Embolisi");
            Twentyfour twentyfour = new Twentyfour();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentyfour).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwenty) {

            setTitle("Genel Anestezik");
           Twentyfive twentyfive = new Twentyfive();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentyfive).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwentyone) {

            setTitle("NDİ - ADH");
            Twentysix twentysix = new Twentysix();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentysix).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwentytwo) {

            setTitle("Glascow Koma");
            Twentyseven twentyseven = new Twentyseven();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentyseven).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwentythree) {

            setTitle("Hipovolemi");
            Twentyeight twentyeight = new Twentyeight();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentyeight).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwentyfour) {

            setTitle("Atrakuryum Bezilat");
            Twentynine twentynine = new Twentynine();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,twentynine).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwentyfive) {

            setTitle("SempatoadrenalHiperaktivasyon");
            Thirty thirty = new Thirty();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,thirty).commit();

        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwentysix) {

            setTitle("CPR Trakeal");
            Thirtyone thirtyone = new Thirtyone();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,thirtyone).commit();


        }
        else if (id == R.id.twotwentyseven) {

            setTitle("Gravimetrik Etki");
            Thirtytwo thirtytwo = new Thirtytwo();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,thirtytwo).commit();


        }



        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout );
       // drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layoutd);
        return true;

    }



}
```

activty_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/baslik"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        />

</ScrollView>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bir">

</FrameLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set your code of Justification_Mode in if condition because min API level is 26.
Kotlin code:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            tv.justificationMode = JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD
        }
```

Java code:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
      tv.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Ali Alaoi.
I didn't think the problem would be solved easily. You're great. 